# Returning Void from a RequestContext method

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Can a method present in the RequestContext method return void?

If my RequestContext looks like this,

```
@Service( value = PersonUtil.class, locator = PersonLocator.class )
public interface PersonRequest extends RequestContext
{

    Request<void> testMethod( Long id );
    ......
}
```

I am getting this error:

Multiple markers at this line
    - Return type for the method is missing
    - Syntax error on token "void", Dimensions expected after

Can we not create a method with return type void? If not, why is it so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void` is just like primitive types like `int` or `boolean`, you can't use it as a type parameter.

And just like you'd use `Integer` instead of `int`, you'll use `Void` here (`java.lang.Void`)

Comment: Thank you.  I had missed that basic thing.